# Select all values in column with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get all these values from table Trouble and paste into Combobox.

[image]

I have this code,but i get **System.ObjectDisposedException** error

```
var items = db.Trouble.Where(u => u.id_Проблемы > 0).Select(u => u.id_Проблемы);

id_Trouble_box.Items.Add(items);
```

Comment: Are both of those lines of code actually next to each other in your code or are they in different locations?

Comment: @DavidG they are both

Comment: They are both *what*?

Comment: @DavidG they are together,sorry

Comment: Items.Add is for adding a single item.  You want AddRange if you're adding multiple at once.  Your code is adding the whole collection as a single item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem this way

```
var items = db.Trouble.Where(u => u.id_Проблемы > 0).Select(u => u.id_Проблемы).ToArray();
for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    id_Trouble_box.Items.Add(items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a .ToArray() at the end.  Perhaps you have it adding items outside a using statement.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should force `Immediately` excution by `.ToArray()` or `ToList()`

```
var items = db.Trouble.Where(u => u.id_Проблемы > 0).Select(u => u.id_Проблемы).ToArray();

id_Trouble_box.Items.Add(items);
```

Read the following thread to have a better understanding.

[LINQ performance - deferred v/s immediate execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872697/linq-performance-deferred-v-s-immediate-execution)

Comment: @NoreChase Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: This will fix the error but the code still won't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select them all then you don't need a Where criteria:

```
var items = db.Trouble();
```

and to add to a combo you could set the DataSource:

```
var items = db.Trouble();
id_Trouble_box.DataSource = items.ToList();
id_Trouble_box.DisplayMember = "columnToShow"; // display column
id_Trouble_box.ValueMember = "id_Проблемы"; // id to get on selection as a value
```

EDIT: For those who don't understand why this answer fixes the error:

```
string defaultConString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{

    Form f = new Form();
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox { Top = 10, Left = 10 };

    f.Controls.Add(cb);

    using (var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString))
    {
        var items = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.ContactName.Contains("a")).Select(c => c.CompanyName);
        cb.Items.Add(items);
    }
    f.Show();
}


public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext(string connectionString)
     : base(connectionString)
  { }
  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
  [Key]
  public string CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  public string ContactName { get; set; }
  // ...
//  public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So how is this supposed to fix an `ObjectDisposedException`?

Comment: @DavidG, maybe because he was trying to add an IQueryable as an argument to Items.Add?

Comment: Then you should say that, otherwise this is just a code dump without explanation.

Comment: I'm not being picky, I'm telling you that you didn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: My apologies for trying to help. Have a nice day.

Comment: @DavidG, You were not trying to help, you were trying to be picky, just because you couldn't see an obvious answer was an answer why.

Comment: @DavidG, I added a demo code for you to understand why it fixes that error which I thought obvious enough.